# r circlize report gap.degree is too large

Tags: r, circlize

I'm trying to plot chord with chordDiagram function in R.circlize package, the reference code similar to "[matrix visualization](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/vignettes/circular_visualization_of_matrix.pdf)"

```
set.seed(999)
chordDiagram(mat)
circos.clear()
```

the error report like:

```
circos.initialize(factors = factors, xlim = xlim) :
  Maybe your `gap.degree` is too large so that there is no space to allocate sectors.
```

and my 'mat' looks like:

```
> str(mat)
 num [1:421, 1:7] 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:421] "BCM,SCM_2,Accept_Dismiss" "BCM,TCU_2,ActualGear" "BCM,ACM_1,AirbagPassengerLED" "BCM,ACM_1,AirbagWarningLamp" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "MMC,RxBuffer" "IC,RxBuffer" "CCU,RxBuffer" "PEPS,RxBuffer" ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your matrix has too many rows. In your case, if rows and columns refer to different elements, there would be 421 + 7 = 428 sectors in the plot. By default there are gaps between every two neighbouring sectors with width of 1 degree. So, in your case the sum of gaps are 428 degree which is larger than the whole circle (360 degrees) and therefore there is no space for drawing sectors.

Comment: thanks a lot, i's great to get response from r.plugin author here. you make wonderful job with circlize, excellent as ggplot.